# Laravel Eloquent multiple pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot, relationship

I'm not sure what would be the best way to define my Eloquent relationships for a slightly annoying data model
[image: Data Model]

`price_band_price_model` is a pivot table between `price_model` and `price_band`
`price_band_models_promotions` is a pivot table between `promotions` and `price_band_price_model` (so a pivot between a model and a pivot).

What would be the best/simplest way to proceed? 
Should I override the `pivot` class to redefine the price_band_price_model and use the new class to make my relationship?
Should I try to use the `hasManyThrough` relationship? or is it just a shortcut?

Any input would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `price_band_price_model` is not a pivot table, since it has a primary key (id)

Comment: It started as a pivot table, I added the id in order to create the new relationship. And it is used through the project as a pivot.

Comment: That's a good approach since Laravel doesn't support a relationship for two pivot tables. so Make a Model for `price_band_price_model` table too.

Comment: After a lot of tinkering I think I will do that. Changing my initial pivot to a 'normal' model. Thanks for the inputs!

Comment: Yeah, I struggled with the same scenario once, and i took that decision too. because I thought being 'pivot' doesn't make any sense if it has used in another table.